# Load executable using powershell but exe does not read .config file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to load the [CRM Plugin tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515%28v=crm.6%29.aspx) using powershell.

I am using the call start-process "D:\PluginTool2011\PluginRegistration.exe" that loads the tool ok but does not read the associated .config file that stores the saved connections and then loads them in the tool

Is there any way using powershell that I can call an exe and make it read the config file?

EDIT: the config file that contains the connection settings is called connections.config not PluginRegistration.exe.config as I thought.

Comment: Now this is guesswork, but did you try to to add -WorkingDirectory D:\PluginTool2011 to the start-process call? Assuming that the tool looks for Connections.cfg in the current working folder.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the -WorkingDirectory D:\PluginTool2011 to the Start-Process assuming that the tool reads the config file from the current working directory.

```
start-process "D:\PluginTool2011\PluginRegistration.exe" -WorkingDirectory D:\PluginTool2011
```