# Loading .exe using PowerShell's Invoke-Command but exe does not read .config file

Tags: powershell

I am currently running an exe using the command below. The .exe runs fine, however, it doesn't read a config file associate with the program. I used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955902/load-executable-using-powershell-but-exe-does-not-read-config-file) and it works. However, I would like to add something like "-WorkingDirectory" but using invoke-command. My end goal is to be able to run the exe as part of the tfs build using this script.

```
$file = 'C:\test.exe'
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Param($myarg) & $file }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the directory as an argument and use `Set-Location` to change the working directory inside the scriptblock:

```
$file = 'C:\test.exe'
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Param($exe, $wd)
    Set-Location $wd
    & $exe
} -ArgumentList $file, 'C:\working\directory'
```

With that said, there's no point in using `Invoke-Command` unless you want to run something on a different computer, with different credentials, or as a background job (or any combination of the aforementioned). Otherwise you could just as well change the directory and run the command directly:

```
Set-Location 'C:\working\directory'
& $file
```